# Time stamp missing

Tags: c#, time, serial-port

I'm trying to display the data received on textbox. But I realized that when data were being received on Br@y terminal it look fine (eg. 14:02:33.43 > T  11  22.32) but running on the software the time stamp is missing.

Am I missing out anything which lead to this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.IO;

namespace SerialCom
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string RxString;  //Variable

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        serialPort1.PortName = "COM4";
        serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;

        serialPort1.Open();
        if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
        {
            btnStart.Enabled = false;
            btnStop.Enabled = true;
            txtData.ReadOnly = false;
        }

     }

    private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
        {
            serialPort1.Close();
            btnStart.Enabled = true;
            btnStop.Enabled = false;
            txtData.ReadOnly = true;
        }

    }

    private void txtData_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {

        if (!serialPort1.IsOpen) return;  // If the port is closed, don't try to send a character.
        char[] buff = new char[8];  // If the port is Open, declare a char[] array with one element.
        buff[0] = e.KeyChar;  // Load element 0 with the key character.
        serialPort1.Write(buff, 0, 1);  // Send the one character buffer.
        e.Handled = true;// Set the KeyPress event as handled so the character won't
        // display locally. If you want it to display, omit the next line.
    }

    private void DisplayText(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtData.AppendText(RxString);
    }

    private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        RxString = serialPort1.ReadExisting();
        this.Invoke(new EventHandler(DisplayText));

        StreamWriter MyStreamWriter = new StreamWriter(@"c:\testing.txt",true);  //True tell SW to append to file instead of overwriting
        MyStreamWriter.Write(RxString);
        MyStreamWriter.Flush();
        MyStreamWriter.Close();
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
            serialPort1.Close();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Are you sure the timestamp is part of the data you receive from the serial line ?

Comment: @AlexandreVinçon Yes, it's part of the data I'm supposed to receive.. but I don't get it why am I not seeing in in the textbox

Comment: Could you please provide a sample of what's really on the serial line (using Portmon tool, for example), and a screenshot of what you get on your screen?

Comment: Is the content of "c:\testing.txt" correct ?

Comment: @AlexandreVinçon no, content of the txt file just reflects what i received

Comment: Then I have to insist: I really suspect that the missing timestamp is not part of the data that is transported by the serial line, but is generated by your terminal software instead. Please use a serial line spy (like Portmon that I already mentioned) and provide the captured data for further analysis.

Comment: @AlexandreVinçon Hey Alex, so sorry for any confusion. I guess I'm wrong with my info, the time stamp reflected should be based on my computer time stamp.. So i had to add in coding like DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");

Comment: I just don't get it anymore...  :(

Comment: @AlexandreVinçon hey! no worries, maybe it was the way i phase my qn/ans.. actually I need the time stamp to show when did i actually had this incoming data being received. (So apparently, this time stamp should not be part of the data being received. I need to include this time function on my own)

Comment: But anyway, the problem is solved :) thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, I was wrong by saying that the time stamp is originally included in the data i received.. I need to add in the time stamp on my own.. This was to act as a record of when did i actually received the following data.

As a result, what's missing is this

```
string time = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.ff")
```

Hope this helps people who are struggling with the problem too.